# Is there any way to disable ORMLite's check that a field declared with DataType.SERIALIZABLE implements Serializable?

Tags: collections, ormlite, serializable

Question title just about says it all.  I have a field declared like this:

```
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull=false,dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    List<ScheduleTriggerPredicate> predicates = Collections.emptyList();
```

Depending on context, `predicates` can either contain the empty list or an immutable list returned by `Collections.unmodifiableList(List)` with an `ArrayList` as its parameter.  I therefore *know* that the object in question is serializable, but there is no way I can tell the compiler (and therefore ORMLite) that it is.  Therefore I get this exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /ADHDWeb threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class java.util.List for field
    FieldType:name=predicates,class=ScheduleTrigger is not valid for type 
    com.j256.ormlite.field.types.SerializableType@967d5f, maybe should be
    interface java.io.Serializable
```

Now, if there was just some way of disabling the check, everything would obviously work fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining a custom data type is pretty well documented in the FM:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-data-types

You can extend the the `SerializableType` class and `@Override` the `isValidForField(...)` method.  In this case, this will serialize collections.

```java
public class SerializableCollectionsType extends SerializableType {
    private static LocalSerializableType singleton;
    public SerializableCollectionsType() {
        super(SqlType.SERIALIZABLE, new Class<?>[0]);
    }
    public static LocalSerializableType getSingleton() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new LocalSerializableType();
        }
        return singleton;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isValidForField(Field field) {
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType());
    }
}
```

To use this you must replace the `dataType` with `persisterClass` in `@DatabaseField`:

```java
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false,
    persisterClass = SerializableCollectionsType.class)
List<ScheduleTriggerPredicate> predicates = Collections.emptyList();
```

I've added to the unit test to show working code with this.  Here's the [github change](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/6a9e49b8154f233fe551e13aea0892d0afaa31e6).

Comment: Thanks.  Should have thought of that... it's kind of obvious in hindsight.

Comment: @Gray What is LocalSerializableType type? the IDE shows some error when I try creating this method

Comment: The code is designed to be an example @DrMido.  The `LocalSerializableType` is what you define.