# Using JodaTime (DateTime, Duration) with ORMLite on Android

Tags: android, jodatime, ormlite

I am looking for a way to hold a DateTime object and a Duration as part of my value object.

Here is my value object:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = DrivingRecord.TableName)
public class DrivingRecord {
    public final static String TableName = "drivingRecord";
    public final static String DRIVING_TASK_COLUMN_NAME = "drivingTask";

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = DRIVING_TASK_COLUMN_NAME)
    private DrivingTask drivingTask;

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG)
    private DateTime startTime;

    @DatabaseField
    private Duration durationOfDriving;
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class org.joda.time.Duration for field FieldType:name=durationOfDriving,class=DrivingRecord is not valid for type com.j256.ormlite.field.types.LongType@41223060, maybe should be long
```

I also getting the same exception when trying to create an entry for the DateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field class org.joda.time.Duration for
    field FieldType:name=durationOfDriving,class=DrivingRecord is not valid for
    type com.j256.ormlite.field.types.LongType@41223060, maybe should be long
```

This message is trying to tell you that your `Duration` field `durationOfDriving` is not compatible with the date-type `DataType.LONG`.  I'm not sure if the code you've posted isn't correct but I would have thought that you would be trying to do:

```java
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG)
private Duration durationOfDriving;
```

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) natively supports `DateTime` but does not support persisting a `Duration`.  Just trying to force it to be a long will not work.  You are going to have to define a customer persister for `Duration`.

Check out the [documentation on custom persisters](http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-data-types) for how to start your own persister.

You can also check out this answer for another example: [Is there any way to disable ORMLite's check that a field declared with DataType.SERIALIZABLE implements Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687160/is-there-any-way-to-disable-ormlites-check-that-a-field-declared-with-datatype/15690590#15690590)

Comment: What about a LocalDateTime? Do I have to write a custom persister for that?

Comment: @simonides LocalDateTime is not supported and throws an error. Use DateTime instead if you want to use Jodatime with ORMLite

Answer (score 1):

Here is show I was able to solve the problem. Making the timestamp a long, and save the timezone. Now I am able to search on the timestamp if I needed to.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = DrivingRecord.TableName)
public class DrivingRecord {
    public final static String TableName = "drivingRecord";
    public final static String DRIVING_TASK_COLUMN_NAME = "drivingTask";

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = DRIVING_TASK_COLUMN_NAME)
    private DrivingTask drivingTask;

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.LONG)
    private long startTime;

    @DatabaseField
    private Duration durationOfDriving;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, dataType= DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    private DateTimeZone timeZone;

    public void setDateTime(DateTime dateTime){
        this.startTime = startTime.getMillis();
        this.timeZone = startTime.getZone();
    }

    public DateTime getDateTime(){
        return new DateTime(startTime, timeZone);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While JodaTime does not work with ORMLite, you can use Java Date which works with ORMLite.
There are also many ways you can convert in between JodaTime and Date.

```
@DatabaseField
protected Date createdAt;

public static String formatDateTime(DateTime dateTime1) {
    if (dateTime1 == null || dateTime1.getYear() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, ApplicationBase.AppContext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
    Calendar calendar02 = new GregorianCalendar(dateTime1.getYear(), dateTime1.getMonthOfYear() - 1, dateTime1.getDayOfMonth());
    Date date3 = calendar02.getTime();
    String date3str = DataItemBase.formatDate(date3);
    return date3str;
}
```