# ORMLite does not know how to store interface java.util.List

Tags: java, ormlite

Product

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Product() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Product(String originalId) {
    this.originalId = originalId;
}

@DatabaseField(id = true)
private String originalId;

...

@DatabaseField
private List<SkuInfo> skusInfo;
```

SkuInfo

```
public class SkuInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ORMLite does not know how to store interface java.util.List for field skusInfo. Use another class or a custom persister.
```

When I used:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
private List<SkuInfo> skusInfo;
```

The error change to:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ORMLite does not know how to store interface java.util.List for field skusInfo. Use another class or a custom persister.
```

I already read in another posts about the tag Foreign but my item is not a foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ORMLite does not know how to store interface java.util.List for field skusInfo. Use another class or a custom persister.`

Just for posterity, you could have changed this to be an `ArrayList` which actually implements `java.io.Serializable` since that's what it is looking for.   Unfortunately the `List` doesn't so ORMLite throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I used a Custom Serializable Object like posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687160/is-there-any-way-to-disable-ormlites-check-that-a-field-declared-with-datatype) and worked.

```
public class SerializableCollectionsType extends SerializableType {
    private static SerializableCollectionsType singleton;
    public SerializableCollectionsType() {
        super(SqlType.SERIALIZABLE, new Class<?>[0]);
    }

    public static SerializableCollectionsType getSingleton() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new SerializableCollectionsType();
        }
        return singleton;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isValidForField(Field field) {
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType());
    }
}
```

Product

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = SerializableCollectionsType.class)
private List<SkuInfo> skusInfo;
```